# Are NSDocument* classes only for document-based applications?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm wondering if NSDocument is only for applications that are text/document-based.  I have an application that uses multiple windows, which together form a project.  Would it be a good idea to implement those windows as NSDocuments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDocument` models a document, but a document doesn't need to be text-based. Typically, it is the in-memory representation of a file on disk. If your application works with files in a particular format (e.g. images or text or code or genomes or graphs...) then `NSDocument` will typically be the correct class to use when modelling those files.

If, however, you have windows which don't model files, `NSDocument` is the wrong tool to use because it is geared toward file manipulation. Instead, you would typically use one `NSWindowController` per window (or per closely-related set of windows) to control your UI.